# MAMP localhost can not provide secure connection

Tags: ssl, server, localhost, mamp

I have been trying to start a Laravel project I grabbed from live site to my localhost, but can't seem to get it running.

It gives me this error.

This site can’t provide a secure connection
localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I have checked renamed deleted any rewrites to to HTTPS in htaccess, cleared cache and cookies, turned off any firewall or antivirus

I'm completely stuck on this one, anyone have any experience?

Thanks,

Edward